# Webhooks are not notified with users used in the Facebook app review process

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I have a customer service application where we have recently added integration for customer service agents to respond to customers via Instagram direct messages.

To achieve this, I follow the following steps:

1. Implement Facebook Login Process
2. Show the user the Facebook pages that have an associated Instagram Business Account.This is achieved using the endpoint:

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={accessToken}&fields=about,name,id,access_token,category,instagram_business_account,picture{{url}},link
   ```
3. When the user selects the page they want to link, I obtain a long-lived token for the selected page using the endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={MyAppId}&client_secret={MyAppSecret}&fb_exchange_token={ShortLiveToken}
```

4. I subscribe the page to my application using this HTTP request:

```json
https://graph.facebook.com/me/subscribed_apps?access_token={pageExtendedToken}
//HTTP POST
//Body
{
     "subscribed_fields": [
            "feed",
            "message_echoes",
            "messages",
            "messaging_postback"            
        ]
}
```

When I test my integration with users who have a role in my application, incoming webhooks and messages sent via the Graph API to Instagram are processed correctly.

**THE ISSUE WITH FACEBOOK APP REVIEW**

I have spent several months trying to successfully pass the Facebook app review, but when the Facebook team uses their test users, I do not receive any webhook notifications.

This issue only happens with the test users Facebook provides, because again, with my own users, it works perfectly.

The Facebook team gave me these alternatives to try to overcome the app review:

**Create a real Instagram account.**

If I provide them with a real Instagram account for testing, the login is blocked with the message 'we detected an unusual login attempt on Instagram,' and it asks for a code sent to the email associated with the account. (That's not possible because even if I provide the email credentials, the login will be blocked for the same reason by the email provider.)

**Create Facebook Test User Accounts for the application**

The option to create test user accounts is disabled by Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/508224331252373/

**Let the Facebook team use their Test Users.**

When the Facebook team uses their test users, the webhook notification NEVER reaches our servers.

Has anyone experienced something similar? If so, how did you manage to overcome the app review process?